# can't override the timeout and put screen to sleep less than the 15 sec. anyone know the trick?

Tags: android, timeout

I can't override the timeout and put screen to sleep less than the 15 sec. anyone know the trick? as noticed, the min setting of android phone is 15 sec and default is 30 sec.

Comment: Doubt that this would be available to you unless you have a rooted phone and would like to modify your own operating system to behave in this manner.  Is this the case?  Otherwise, it would allow for a program to keep a phone/device from being useable.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that it can't be done on a non-rooted device. This is a level 2 permission (limited to system applications/processes), and Android refuses to grant access to it no matter what you do, at least from what I have heard. Sorry :(